# How to ignore a match based on a word if it appears before the match

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have something like below

```
Payment Instrument modified. payment no: 5000000000000000, method: C for transponder: 5000000000000000 transponder type: A
```

In the above my regex need to match only 5000000000000000 which appeared after `payment no:`

Pattern: `([payment no:  ][0-9]{4}[0-9]{0,16})([0-9]{4})`

Comment: does it need to match that number exactly or just any number?

Comment: need to mask the number leaving the last four.

Comment: mask the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=payment no: )\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/xvXcGG/1)

- `(?<=payment no: )` makes sure there is `payment no:` before your match
- `\d+` matches any digit 1 or more times.

---

A version without the lookbehind would be [`payment no: (\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xvXcGG/2/)

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/xvXcGG/1)

Comment: Thanks that worked